# Can a simple JSp and servlet code be migrated to Spring framework?

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, struts

I am a newbie in web development. I'm using servlets and JSP for web development.However, I've learnt lately that Spring Framework is apt for that which incorporate servlets, jsp etc. So, my question is that can I now run my program using Spring framework ? Like, I have 2 jsp codes, and 1 servlet class. So, how can I migrate the code in Spring Framework ? what additional things or codes do I need to maintain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating an existing J2EE project is easy.
You will get rid of a lot of "boilerplate" code in the process. The easiest way to do it in my opinion will be to use SpringToolSuite. 
Import your project in STS and then add "Maven" nature to it. In the pom configuration you can edit all the jars that you need and mention the spring framework. Once all this is setup it will be just a matter of minutes to change the code if it is small.

You can follow these video tutorials about maven and spring to learn about it.
[JavaBrains](http://javabrains.koushik.org/courses.html)

There are more tutorials by "New Circle training" on youtube for the same.

I would also recommend you to read [Spring in action 3rd edition-Manning](http://www.manning.com/walls4/)

This book is a must and the best way to learn spring framework. Hope this helps

Comment: What disadvantage can I face if I continue in the same fashion i.e without using Spring framework ?

Comment: The only disadvantage you will face is that you will make your code too complex and "boilerplate" while you have technologies like Spring available to do most of the work. Once you use spring you will understand how easy it has become to develop a java application. I have seen ten's of thousand lines of code change to merely 100's line of code by using spring framework

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me Nikhil ! Just tell me one more thing. Is there any tutorial/pdf (short but effective) that lets me know how a sample website with database connectivity be established through Eclipse. I've already made my controller class (.java program) and my view in jsp. So I want to migrate to Spring very soon with the basic knowledge. So let me know if you know any such kind of pdf or video tutorials at your disposal. Thanks !

Comment: One more question ! If I know the basic working of servlets and JSP, how soon can I migrate to Spring framework ? Actually, I need to transform my code in Spring framework urgently ! so how can I do that in the least time ? :)

Comment: You can convert your project to use spring framework within a couple of hours (depends on expertise and assuming that your troubleshooting skills are good). In the link i gave you for javabrains, you will find tutorials for database connectivity using spring in eclipse. You can follow that - If you know "Data source" configuration in J2EE then that should be pretty straight forward.