# migrating a large-scale, poorly structured Java system to Spring application framework

Tags: java, spring, architecture, migration

I'm looking for development stories/experiences on migrating a Java system 
to Spring Application Framework. our aim is the benefits of a bean container and the dependency injection of Spring. We're not considering Spring MVC or any other of its specific components at the time.

Our system is currently using no bean container of any kind. all in pure Java-- nothing of JEE either.

It has its own, house-built service engines for managing Db services, 
in-memory caches, session mngt, configuration, and certain product-specific components. 
what's more, it is poorly structured. very poorly encapsulated -- needs lots of refactoring, 
elimination of duplicate and unused code, bug fixing. 
a good amount of our development efforts are going into bug-fixing rather than structural -- making it 
even further deteriorate. it's a 10+ year-old system and has been built around its original architecture.

We aren't even sure yet whether to work on its existing structure first 
then look to get the benefits of Spring, 
or to do them both at once.

To me, working a new architecture from scratch on Spring that implements the logic and not the structure of the 
current system is the best. however, this may/not be as feasible since it won't have tangible results in 
a near-enough future for the upper management.

I'll appreciate direct/indirect references opinions, experiences and other input.

TIA.

//=====================================

EDIT:

so - in a phrase, this is on "***how to migrate a dinosaur to Spring***". it's a matter of strategy-- not of technical migration like how/where 
to organize/define/integrate the specific components.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534396/can-a-simple-jsp-and-servlet-code-be-migrated-to-spring-framework

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy thx but this won't help. pls see the edit. in fact our servlet is one of the best functional components.

Comment: You have an architecture reengineering task.  Not for Java, but a similar problem for C++: see this techinical paper on how to automate this kind of thing: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/WCRE05.pdf  That describes the project halfway through. There's a paper on the final result behind a paywall; if you want that reference I'll dig it up.

Comment: How big is the code base?

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by creating a migration plan that...

- Converts as many of the legacy java classes/functions you can into bean format.
- Swaps out legacy code with built in Spring libraries such as database access, security, etc. and/or wrap Spring libraries with the legacy interfaces to migrate off legacy code
- Devises a way to run both the legacy system and the new system together while slowly transitioning elements from the legacy system to the new system

Answer (score 0):

First, see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/when-is-a-big-rewrite-the-answer) article. If you fulfill the requirement for server migration, then continue. If you don't think so, then drop your plan.

If you think that you only need to replace some parts inside the system and not the whole system, you need to consider whether the benefit will outdone the cost. There is a guidance that says "if it works, don't change", because any change to an existing code increase the risk of being error. Are you sure that Spring will bring all the benefits that you think of? Moreover, the amount of tests initiated to reduce the risk is also costly.

That aside, if you still insist that you need to do the migration whatever the costs, I suggest that you rebuilding the new system separated from old one while still maintaining the old one. Then you will need to implement the new system partially under the same database and not total cutoff.